# Setting priorities for pthreads with mutex

Tags: c, synchronization, pthreads, mutex

I was curious how you go about setting priorities for pthreads using a mutex in C.  I want to be sure my threads receive the lock in the order they should based off some priority value.  I've done a little digging and found

```
pthread_mutexattr_getprotocol()
```

and

```
pthread_mutexattr_setprotocol()
```

Is this something that accomplishes what I want to do?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see where mutexes fit into this - thread priority

```
 pthread_setschedparam(pthread_t thread, int policy,
                         const struct sched_param *param);
   pthread_getschedparam(pthread_t thread, int *policy,
                         struct sched_param *param);
```

Try those.  Assuming I understand what you want...

Try `pthread_barrier_wait` to force threads to wait for everybody else to complete something.

Comment: After more search I realized the two I listed were not relevant.  And say 10 threads are trying to grab the mutex.  I'd like it to be able to give the mutex to the thread in order of a set priority.  Is this still what I want?

Comment: It might work, but trying to order execution of threads is a messy deal.  pthread_set_barrier_wait may be what you are looking for.  It is called barrier synchronization.  Given your confusion, I'm not sure anything I've posted is what you want.  But this seems like it to me.

Comment: @Robert, no, not exactly.  Basically it means that a lower priority thread holding the mutex will get the highest priority of any threads waiting on the mutex (PRIO_INHERIT); or any thread will run at the higher of its priority or the priority ceiling of any mutex it is holding initialed with PRIO_PROTECT.  These are mostly for avoiding priority inversion deadlocks.  Nothing really (other than something you code for yourself) can really guarantee your "threads receive the lock in the order they should".

Comment: @Duck you can use barriers to force "everybody " to wait for stragglers, which seems like what the OP wants, not some kind of priority boost.  And you are right, there is no way guarantee order of thread execution.

Comment: We... like jim/Duck says, you could expliitly manage it yourself.  That means a more complex lock-struct with an internal mutex-protected state-machine with containers of waiting threads and condvars/semaphores on which they are waiting. Don't try this at home.